# Save file to windows shared drive on button click

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am currently working on an app that generates xlsx files based on user input. At the moment the users are able to download the xlsx file on their device by clicking on a download button. I am wondering if there is a possibility to have those files saved on a windows shared drive when clicking on a specific button.

Thank you!

Comment: The browser user can decide to save the file anywhere they want. Your code cannot make the decision for them.

Comment: Are you trying to save the file to the destination from server-side code?  Does the server have any access to that destination?  Or are you trying to suggest a path for saving the file when returning the file to the client?  Something else?  It's not clear to me specifically what you're attempting.

Comment: Hi, basically at the moment the users have to manually move those downloaded files to a specific shared drive. What I am trying to achieve is to have those file saved directly to the shared drive without having the users manually adding them and I am not sure how should I do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible what you are trying to achieve.